# Oracle to retrieve maximum record

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

```
Table_A

A_id          
1     



Tale_B
B_id       A_id
1            1
2            1
3            1

Table_C

B_id      Process_date
1   20130101 12:20:01
2   20130101 12:10:01
3   20130101 13:00:01
```

How to retrieve the maximum process_date from Table_C with references of Table_A A_id based on Table_C timing window.If i want to retrieve Table_C id and max(process_date) in timing window 20130101 12:09:00 to 12:21:00 then it should return id as 1 and process_date as 12:20:01

Comment: You should try something and come back to ask why you're not getting the expected result. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) will help you to post your question on the right way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery that gets the `max(process_date)`:

```
select c1.b_id,
  c2.MaxDate
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
  on a.a_id = b.a_id
inner join table_c c1
  on b.b_id = c1.b_id
inner join
(
  select max(process_date) MaxDate
  from table_c
) c2
  on c1.process_date = c2.maxdate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e80c/9)

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select b_id, process_date
from 
(
  select c1.b_id,
    c1.process_date,
    row_number() over(partition by a.a_id order by c1.process_date desc) rn
  from table_a a
  inner join table_b b
    on a.a_id = b.a_id
  inner join table_c c1
    on b.b_id = c1.b_id
) 
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e80c/10)

Comment: :Thanks,it is giving duplicated when i retrieve b_id,process_date

Comment: @user2127414 can you expand your sample data? And then show the desired result?

Comment: I want 3,13:00:01 from Table_c

Comment: @user2127414 see my edit, I was returning `a_id` but you just need to change it to `b_id` and you will get the result.

Comment: i added this condition to retrieve first record from table c  ( TO_CHAR(src.PROCESS_DATE,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')  between   ('20130228'||' '|| '12:11:01') and  ('20130301'||' '||'12:21:00') 
).It is not giving expected result : 1 and 20130101

Comment: what is datatype of process_date?

Comment: It should return id and Max(process_date) from table in that timing window

Comment: i have 20 lakhs records in each table,query is very slow with row_num solution.Indexes already present.How to improve the performance?

Comment: @user2127414 Please post a new question with your issues.

Comment: Only issue is performance, how to use rownum with above requirement

Comment: Raised different question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259989/how-to-improve-oracle-row-number-in-query

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you the max `process_date` for each `B_id` with a reference in `Table_A`:

```
SELECT c.B_id, MAX(Process_date)
FROM Table_C c
INNER JOIN Table_B b 
    ON b.B_id = c.B_id
INNER JOIN Table_A a
    ON a.A_ID = b.A_id
GROUP BY c.B_id
```

Just remove the `c.B_id` from the select and the `GROUP BY` if you want the max `process_date` of all B_id's with a reference to `Table_A`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eb56/1)